# problem to receive flutterLocalNotifications notifications when installing the apk on android

Tags: flutter, dart

I finished my application in development mode. By running directly on the device, I receive notifications at the scheduled time. When I install the compiled apk I no longer receive notifications problem to receive notifications;

```
 flutterLocalNotifications
```

Here's the notification details:

```
 NotificationDetails(
                        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                          notificationChannelId,
                          'Various',
                          ongoing: true,
                          icon: "@drawable/ic",
                          colorized: true,
                          largeIcon: const DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('ic'),
                          color: blanc(),
                          //showWhen: true,
                          importance: Importance.max,
                          priority: Priority.high,
                          styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(
                            "Hello dear Customer of HOREB fidelity, Congratulations you still have  ${int.parse(item.montantCumules) - int.parse(item.totalAchat)} FCFA purchases at ${item.nom} to trigger the obtaining of your points. act now !! \n",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

show me the technical issues to resolve, please;